# Программа для стеганографии текстовых сообщений

Tags: c, строки, файлы, инспекция-кода, стеганография

Простая программа позволяет прятать текстовые сообщения в текстовых файлах следующим образом:

1. Текстовое сообщение переводится в двоичный код;
2. В конце каждой строки файла перед символом перевода строки записывается символ пробела, если текущий бит сообщения равен единице, иначе не записывается ничего.

Предполагается, что количества строк в файле достаточно, чтобы вместить сообщение. Также предполагается, что изначально в файле нет ни одной строки, в конце которой записан пробел (для однозначного декодирования).

Некоторые примечания к коду:

1. В коде *нет обработки ошибок* для упрощения программы. Вместо обработки ошибок используется множество asserts;
2. Я написал собственные аналоги `strdup` и `strrev`, т. к. обе они не входят в стандарт. Свои реализации я назвал `duplicateString` и `reverseString` соответственно, так как имена `str*` зарезервированы стандартом;
3. Я проверяю валидность входных аргументов для предотвращения ошибок использования внутреннего API;
4. Все функции объявлены статическими, потому что находятся в одной единице трансляции.
5. *Входной файл открывается в текстовом режиме, в то время как временный файл всегда открывается в бинарном режиме (`w+b`). Может ли это привести к каким-то проблемам?*

#### Компилятор

Я использую Clang со следующими ключами:

```
-std=c11
-Weverything
-Wpedantic
-fsanitize=address
-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Компилятор выдает только одно предупреждение:

```
warning: implicit conversion turns floating-point number into integer: 'double' to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned int') [-Wfloat-conversion]
        const size_t newCapacity = ceil(s->capacity * DYNAMIC_STRING_GROW_FACTOR);
```

Не вижу смысла его исправлять.

#### Статический анализатор кода

Также я проверил код анализатором CppCheck и он выдал одну ошибку: «*Memory leak: ret in function stringToBinary*»:

```
char *stringToBinary(const char *s)
{
    assert(s);
    assert(strlen(s) > 0);

    char *ret = calloc((strlen(s) + 1) * CHAR_BIT + 1, 1);
    assert(ret);

    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        strcat(ret, charToBinary(s[i]));

    return strcat(ret, charToBinary('\0'));
}
```

Но, похоже, это ложное срабатывание, поскольку `res` освобождается в функции `hideMessage`:

```
char *msgBinary = stringToBinary(msg);
...
free(msgBinary);
```

---

Собственно, код:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define DYNAMIC_STRING_GROW_FACTOR 1.5

typedef struct DynamicString {
    char *s;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t length;
} DynamicString;

static void  createDynamicString(DynamicString *, size_t);
static void  destroyDynamicString(DynamicString *);
static void  increaseDynamicStringCapacity(DynamicString *);
static void  appendCharToDynamicString(DynamicString *, char);
static void  hideMessage(FILE *, const char *);
static char *extractMessage(FILE *);
static void  copyFile(FILE *, FILE *);
static char *stringToBinary(const char *);
static char *charToBinary(char);
static char  charFromBinary(const char *);
static char *reverseString(char *);
static char *duplicateString(const char *s);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r+");
    assert(file);

    hideMessage(file, "hello, world");

    char *msg = extractMessage(file);
    assert(msg);
    puts(msg);

    free(msg);
    fclose(file);
}

/* The HIDEMESSAGE function
 *
 * The function hides text message into the file by that way: 1) the message
 * converts to binary; 2) each bit of the converted message writes at the end
 * of each file's line (right before the new-line character): if the bit
 * is 1 then a space (' ') appends to the line otherwise it's nothing appends
 * to the line.
 *
 * Assumes the the file does not contain any spaces right before new-line
 * characters. Also assumes that the file has enough lines for storing
 * the message.
 */
void hideMessage(FILE *f, const char *msg)
{
    assert(f);
    assert(msg);
    assert(strlen(msg) > 0);

    char *msgBinary = stringToBinary(msg);
    assert(msgBinary);

    FILE *tempFile = tmpfile();
    assert(tempFile);

    for (int ch, i = 0; (ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF;) {
        if (msgBinary[i] && (ch == '\n'))
            if (msgBinary[i++] == '1')
                fputc(' ', tempFile);

        fputc(ch, tempFile);
    }

    copyFile(f, tempFile);

    free(msgBinary);
    fclose(tempFile);
}

/* The EXTRACTMESSAGE function
 *
 * The function extracts message hidden by the HIDEMESSAGE function from
 * the input file and returns a pointer to heap-allocated string which
 * contains the message.
 */
char *extractMessage(FILE *f)
{
    assert(f);

    DynamicString msgBuffer;
    createDynamicString(&msgBuffer, 128);

    char charInBinary[CHAR_BIT + 1] = {0};

    for (int prevCh = 0, ch, i = 0; (ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF; prevCh = ch) {
        if (ch == '\n')
            charInBinary[i++] = (prevCh == ' ') ? '1' : '0';

        if (i % CHAR_BIT == 0 && i != 0) {
            if (!strcmp(charInBinary, charToBinary('\0')))
                break;

            i = 0;
            appendCharToDynamicString(&msgBuffer, charFromBinary(charInBinary));
        }
    }

    char *ret = duplicateString(msgBuffer.s);
    assert(ret);

    destroyDynamicString(&msgBuffer);
    return ret;
}

/* The CREATEDYNAMICSTRING function
 *
 * The function initializes a DynamicString passing by the first argument.
 * The initial capacity of the string is passing by the second argument.
 * Capacity is the max length of the string. At the same time length is
 * current length of the string. Thus the function allocates capacity + 1
 * bytes for the string (considering the null-character).
 *
 * The input pointer to DynamicString struture should be a valid pointer and
 * capacity should be greater than 0.
 */
void createDynamicString(DynamicString *ret, size_t capacity)
{
    assert(ret);
    assert(capacity > 0);

    ret->s = malloc(capacity + 1);
    assert(ret->s);

    ret->length = 0;
    ret->capacity = capacity;
}

/* The APPENDCHARTODYNAMICSTRING function
 *
 * The function appends a character to the input DynamicString. If capacity of
 * the string is not enough the function increases it.
 *
 * The input pointer to a DynamicString should be a valid pointer as well as
 * its string buffer.
 */
void appendCharToDynamicString(DynamicString *s, char c)
{
    assert(s);
    assert(s->s);

    if (s->length == s->capacity)
        increaseDynamicStringCapacity(s);

    s->s[s->length++] = c;
    s->s[s->length] = '\0';
}

/* The INCREASEDYNAMICSTRINGCAPACITY function
 *
 * The function increases capacity of the input DynamicString. Grow factor
 * is sets by a macro constant DYNAMIC_STRING_GROW_FACTOR.
 *
 * The input pointer to a DynamicString struture should be a valid pointer
 * as well as its string buffer.
 */
void increaseDynamicStringCapacity(DynamicString *s)
{
    assert(s);
    assert(s->s);

    const size_t newCapacity =  ceil(s->capacity * DYNAMIC_STRING_GROW_FACTOR);

    s->s = realloc(s->s, newCapacity + 1);
    assert(s->s);

    s->capacity = newCapacity;
}

/* The DESTROYDYNAMICSTRING function
 *
 * The function destroys the input DynamicString. It frees the string buffer
 * of the input DynamicString.
 *
 * The input pointer to a DynamicString should be a valid pointer as well as
 * its string buffer.
 */
void destroyDynamicString(DynamicString *s)
{
    assert(s);
    assert(s->s);

    free(s->s);
}

/* The COPYFILE function
 *
 * The function copies all the contents of src to dest. Both arguments should
 * be valid pointers. dest should be open for writing, src should be open
 * for reading. The function does not close the files. The both file cursor
 * position sets to the beginning.
 */
void copyFile(FILE *dest, FILE *src)
{
    assert(dest);
    assert(src);

    rewind(dest);
    rewind(src);

    for (int ch; (ch = fgetc(src)) != EOF;)
        fputc(ch, dest);

    rewind(dest);
    rewind(src);
}

/* The CHARFROMBINARY function
 *
 * The function converts the input string returned by the CHARTOBINARY function
 * to a character.
 *
 * The input string should be a valid null-terminated string and its length
 * should be greater 0.
 *
 * charFromBinary(charToBinary(c)) == c
 */
char charFromBinary(const char *s)
{
    assert(s);
    assert(strlen(s) > 0);

    char ret = 0;
    unsigned int p = 1;

    for (size_t i = strlen(s); i-- > 0; p *= 2)
        if (s[i] == '1')
            ret += p;

    return ret;
}

/* The STRINGTOBINARY function
 *
 * The function converts the input string to binary form and returns a pointer
 * to heap-allocated null-terminated string. Null-terminator of the input
 * string also converts to binary form and appends to the result. The caller
 * should free memory allocated for the output string.
 *
 * The input string should be a valid null-terminated string and its length
 * should be greater 0.
 *
 * stringToBinary("cat") => "01100011011000010111010000000000"
 * stringToBinary("dog") => "01100100011011110110011100000000"
 * stringToBinary("R\0") => "0101001000000000"
 */
char *stringToBinary(const char *s)
{
    assert(s);
    assert(strlen(s) > 0);

    char *ret = calloc((strlen(s) + 1) * CHAR_BIT + 1, 1);
    assert(ret);

    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        strcat(ret, charToBinary(s[i]));

    return strcat(ret, charToBinary('\0'));
}

/* The CHARTOBINARY function
 *
 * The function converts value of the input character to binary form and
 * returns a pointer to the static null-terminated string which contains
 * the result. The result contains leading zeroes.
 *
 * charToBinary(100) => "01100100"
 * charToBinary('A') => "01000001"
 * charToBinary('\0') => "00000000"
 */
char *charToBinary(char c)
{
    static char ret[CHAR_BIT + 1];

    memset(ret, '0', sizeof ret);
    ret[sizeof ret - 1] = '\0';

    for (size_t i = 0; c; i++) {
        ret[i] = (c % 2) ? '1' : '0';
        c /= 2;
    }

    return reverseString(ret);
}

/* The REVERSESTRING function
 *
 * The input string should be a valid pointer to a null-terminated string.
 * If the input string is empty the function does noting.
 *
 * reverseString("hello") => "olleh"
 * reverseString("a") => "a"
 * reverseString("") => "a"
 */
char *reverseString(char *s)
{
    assert(s);

    char *begin = s;
    char *end = s + strlen(s) - 1;

    for (; begin < end; begin++, end--) {
        const char t = *begin;
        *begin = *end;
        *end = t;
    }

    return s;
}

/* The DUPLICATESTRING function
 *
 * The function returns a pointer to a heap-allocated string, which is a
 * duplicate of the input string. The returned pointer can be passed to the
 * free function.
 */
char *duplicateString(const char *s)
{
    assert(s);
    assert(strlen(s) > 0);

    char *copy = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    assert(copy);

    return strcpy(copy, s);
}
```

#### Update

[Переписанная версия (Github Gist)](https://gist.github.com/Eanmos/00b33bae3bf6567dc6a1275cd69c14da) (учтены замечания @avp и @Edward с [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221871/171517)).

<sub>P. S. Комментарии писал на ломанном английском, надеюсь хоть что-то будет понятно :)</sub>

Comment: И что вы хотите? Спросить, можно ли короче? Думаю, вполне.

Comment: @avp, у вопроса же метка `[инспекция-кода]`.

Comment: Может лучше обсудить *алгоритм*? На мой взгляд, в подобной программе вообще почти ничего в памяти хранить не надо. Посимвольный ввод, подсчет пробелов (для чистки лишних в конце входной строки) и все. Конец можно обозначить кодированным в вашем стиле нулем (считаем, что передаем текст, пусть даже в utf-8)

Comment: @avp, так в памяти особо ничего и не храниться. Запись сообщения реализована точно так как вы и пишете. Или я вас неправильно понял?

Comment: Рассмотрим, например, `stringToBinary()`. Зачем она нужна (вместе со всеми функциями, которые она вызывает), если можно просто выбирать биты по их индексам из исходного сообщения.

Comment: В `extractMessage()` тоже можно побитно заполнять один `char ch = 0;` и после вставки каждого 8-го бита добавлять его (`ch`) к динамическому массиву. Уйма кода со всеми в общем-то бессмысленными проверками сразу уйдет

Comment: @avp, я даже и не подумал об этом сначала. Переписал, получилось, и правда, гораздо короче. Спасибо большое, можете оформить как ответ и глянуть новую версию?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94658/discussion-between-avp-and-eanmos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eanmos, почитал код в гите. На мой взгляд нормально, лучше чем было в первом варианте.

Несколько замечаний.

1) Я не нашел, как **кодируется конец сообщения** при записи в файл. Такое впечатление, что его надо будет обнаруживать по нулевым байтам в конце, которые  *неявно* появятся после записи в достаточно длинный файл.
Может его стоит обозначить явно, например, записав 2 пробела в конец первой строки, идущей после сообщения (перед копированием остатка файла)?

2) При разборе `argc/argv` в `main()` надо проверять количество аргументов для `--hide`
Иначе свалится в `fopen(argv[3], ...)`

3) Наверное стоит проверять `assert(ferror(infile) == 0);` после чтения `EOF`, а также проверить `fclose(outfile)` на предмет IO errors (реально запись на диск может и не поймать, но все же, раз уж вы результат `malloc/realloc` проверяете ..., то эту паранойю надо держать до конца -)).

4) Очевидно, что после `duplicateString(msgBuffer.s)` в `extractMessage()` память надо либо освобождать,
 либо вместо ее вызова можно просто возвращать весь выделенный `malloc/realloc`-ами буфер
(или если хотите фрагментировать память -), то можно вернуть
`realloc(msgBuffer.s,  msgBuffer.length + 1)`)

Еще одно.
Мелочь, но умножение на 1.5 можно сделать в целых: `n * 2 - n / 2` (или сдвигами, если компайлер плохо оптимизирует, то: `(n << 1) - (n >> 1)`).
И еще мелочь. В принципе, в `char` может быть не 8 бит, а `CHAR_BIT` (из `<limits.h>`) и тогда 0x80, которую вы используете в цикле по битам, не играет.
Я бы рекомендовал просто
`for (int j = 0; j < CHAR_BIT; j++) {if (encodeBit(infile, outfile, *msg & (1 << j)) == EOF) ... }`
(да, я понимаю, что тут порядок бит в байте обратный вашему, но мне он кажется более естественным).

Возвращаясь к моему замечанию 3) о `duplicateString()`. В общем, я имел в виду, что она совсем не нужна.
Но если бы она понадобилась, то в контексте использования `struct DynamicString` вместо вызова `strlen()` в ней надо использовать `.length` из структуры `DynamicString` и уж по любому `memcpy()` вместо `strcpy()`, поскольку уже в вызове `malloc()` размер строки известен.